# Can I use a Bag of Tricks to break an Arcane Lock?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

If a door has Arcane Lock cast on it, can I use the fuzzy ball from a rust bag of tricks, stick it in the keyhole, and it grows into a brown bear?

Can that break the lock/door or will I end up with bear paste?

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121416/23064) was your answer and you're posting it as a separate question, if it is, you seem to have made a second account. Take a look [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to see how you can merge them.

Answer (score 12):

### This sort of question is why Gamemasters exist.

In D&D, the Dungeonmaster is given the enormous responsibility of interpreting the rules,, especially when players get creative with them. The DM must decide if the key hole is large enough (or the fuzzy ball small enough), what the DC is to open the door (including the bonus conferred by Arcane Lock) and what sort of damage a growing bear would do, and whether it wouldn't just be forced out of the keyhole as it grew. It could even damage the door so as to make it unopenable to future attempts. Also, technically, the bag requires the fuzzy ball to be thrown (even if only an inch). A DM may be a stickler for this and say that throwing the ball into a keyhole is just plain impossible.

There is nothing carved in stone about any of these decisions.

Which is a roundabout way of saying, "this is a question you must ask your Dungeonmaster". There is no rule to cover all of the variables, and this situation will run differently at every table.

Comment: This is backed up by Jeremy Crawford, lead designer, [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/981248594836520960)